# MYSQL databases refusing to be accesed after reboot

Tags: mysql, linux

Every time I reboot my computer and try to access my mysql database it produces the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000):  
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: can you run 'sudo systemctl status mysqld' and put the output in the question ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. [https://unix.stackexchange.com/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your MySQL is not started automatically on system start-up. Kindly execute `mysqld` to start the MySQL.

---

Or please refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/416309/start-mysql-on-startup, to start MySQL on system start-up, assuming that you are on Linux OS.